# Prove that all group objects and special morphisms of some category $C$ form a category.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

> Prove that all group objects and special morphisms of some category $C$ form a category.

I can see that the objects of this category are the group objects of $C$ and the morphisms are the special morphisms from $C$, but I don't understand how to define composition for this.

Below is the definition Rotman uses to define a category.

[image]

I don't understand what exactly what the composition is here, is it the function $q$ that maps $q : \text{Hom}(A,B) \times \text{Hom}(B,C) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,C)$? Or is composition the name of the image of an element $(f,g)$?

And how exactly would I define composition for this new category?

---

Below is the definition of a special morphism:

[image]

Comment: What are "special" morphisms here?

Comment: The definition has been added to the question.

Comment: OK.  Isn't the composition of two special morphisms also special, so your composition descends to this subcategory of group objects?

Comment: So since the composition of two special morphisms is special and the special morphisms are subsets of the normal morphisms: the category is in fact the subcategory of $C$?

Comment: Firstly you need to prove that the composition of two special morphisms is special. Secondly you need to show that the composition of three special morphisms is associative. Thirdly you need to show that identity morphisms for each group object are special.

The first and third points are each one line and the second you get for free.

Comment: It's not exactly a subcategory, because in general an object can have more than one group structure, so being a group object is not a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up the comments and answering the question:

- Yes, the functions $q:\hom(A,B)\times\hom(B,C)\to\hom(A,C)$ altogether are referred as the *composition* of the given category. And, for morphisms $f,g$, the image $q(f,g)$ is also called the 'composition' of $f$ and $g$.
- The composition of the new category is inherited from $\mathcal C$, so it is already given to be associative, and then this exercise boils down to proving that composition of special morphisms and the identity morphisms are special.
- The category of group objects of $\mathcal C$ is not exactly a subcategory of $\mathcal C$, as an object may have more than one group structure (as it happens e.g. in $\mathcal Set$). 
   
  Instead, we have a *forgetful functor* to $\mathcal C$ that 'forgets the group structure' on the group objects (and the special morphisms are sent to themselves).